# ¿Como hacer que se intercambien de posición solo div con misma clase?

Tags: jquery, div

Estoy intentando hacer que los `div` la clase `.random` se intercambien de posición entre si y que los que tengan la clase `.norandom` se mantengan en su posición.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  var cards = $(".random");
  for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
      var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length -1) + 1;
      var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length -1) +1;
      cards.eq(target).before(cards.eq(target2));
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="norandom">
  <div class="name">fijo</div>
  <div class="info">1</div>
</div>
<div class="random">
  <div class="name">lala2</div>
  <div class="info">2</div>
</div>
<div class="random">
  <div class="name">lala3</div>
  <div class="info">3</div>
</div>
<div class="norandom">
  <div class="name">fijo</div>
  <div class="info">4</div>
</div>
<div class="norandom">
  <div class="name">fijo</div>
  <div class="info">5</div>
</div>
<div class="random">
  <div class="name">lala6</div>
  <div class="info">6</div>
</div>
<div class="random">
  <div class="name">lala7</div>
  <div class="info">7</div>
</div>
<div class="norandom">
  <div class="name">fijo</div>
  <div class="info">8</div>
</div>
<div class="norandom">
    <div class="name">lala9</div>
    <div class="info">9 siempre fijo</div>
</div>
```

El tema es que efectivamente mezcla los con clase `.random` pero los que tienes `class.norandom` se mueven igual.

Aca ejemplo
 http://pruebas.zona8.cl/jaime/randomdivs/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer no es mover los elementos, es insertar en un índice aleatorio específico el `html` de otro elemento, obviamente solamente entran los índices de los elementos con clase `.random`.

Te dejo el ejemplo funcional:

```js
var cards = $(".tarjeta");
var posiciones = [];
var html = [];

// Recorremos todas las tarjetas sin importar la clase
for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
  if(cards[i].getAttribute('class') == 'random tarjeta'){
    //Capturamos las pociones de los elementos con clase random y lo guardamos en un array
    posiciones.push(cards.index(cards[i]));
    // Campturamos el contenido de los elementos con clase random y lo guardamos en un array
    html.push($(cards[i]).html());
  }
}

//Revolvemos los valores ingresados al array posiciones
posiciones.sort(function() {return Math.random() - 0.5});

//Recorremos el array de posiciones ya con sus valores alterados aleatoriamente, añadimos a la tarjeta en el índice aleatorio el html del índice actual
for(var i = 0; i < posiciones.length; i++){
  $(cards[posiciones[i]]).html(html[i]);
}
```

```css
.random, .norandom{
    margin: 8px;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 221px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="norandom tarjeta">
       <div class="name">fijo</div>
      <div class="info">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random tarjeta">
       <div class="name">lala2</div>
      <div class="info">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random tarjeta">
       <div class="name">lala3</div>
      <div class="info">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="norandom tarjeta">
       <div class="name">fijo</div>
      <div class="info">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="norandom tarjeta">
       <div class="name">fijo</div>
      <div class="info">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random tarjeta">
       <div class="name">lala6</div>
      <div class="info">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random tarjeta">
       <div class="name">lala7</div>
      <div class="info">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="norandom tarjeta">
       <div class="name">fijo</div>
      <div class="info">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="norandom tarjeta">
       <div class="name">lala9</div>
      <div class="info">9 siempre fijo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchismas gracias!!! Funcionó de maravillas

Comment: @jrami me alegra mucho que te funcionara como esperabas, te recomiendo marcar la respuesta como aceptada para finalizar la pregunta y que sirva como ayuda a otros desarrolladores, saludos!